# Modifying Hyperlink with openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm trying to modify a hyperlink inside a word document.  The hyperlink is originally pointing to a bookmark in a external document.   What I want to do is change it to point to an internal bookmark that as the same Anchor.

Here's the code I use... It seem to work when I what the variables but when I look at the saved document it is exactly like the original.

What is the reason my chances don't persist?

```
// read file specified in stream 
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\TEMPO\\smartbook\\text1.docx"));
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);

MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

// The first hyperlink -- it happens to be the one I want to modify 
Hyperlink hLink = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Hyperlink>().FirstOrDefault();
if (hLink != null)
{
    // get hyperlink's relation Id (where path stores)
    string relationId = hLink.Id;
    if (relationId != string.Empty)
    {
        // get current relation
        HyperlinkRelationship hr = mainPart.HyperlinkRelationships.Where(a => a.Id == relationId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (hr != null)
        {
            // remove current relation
            mainPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(hr);
            // add new relation with relation 
            // mainPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("C:\\TEMPO\\smartbook\\test.docx"), false, relationId);
        }
    }

    // change hyperlink attributes
    hLink.DocLocation = "#";
    hLink.Id = "";
    hLink.Anchor = "TEST";
}
// save stream to a new file
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\TEMPO\\smartbook\\test.docx", stream.ToArray());
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not yet saved your OpenXmlPackage when you write the stream ...

```
// types that implement IDisposable are better wrapped in a using statement
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TEMPO\smartbook\text1.docx")))
{
   using(var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
   {
      // do all your changes
      // call doc.Close because that SAVES your changes to the stream
      doc.Close(); 
   }
   // save stream to a new file
   File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\TEMPO\smartbook\test.docx", stream.ToArray());
}
```

The [`Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close(v=office.14).aspx) method states explicitly:

> Saves and closes the OpenXml package plus all underlying part streams.

You could also set the `AutoSave` property to true in which case the OpenXMLPackage will be saved when `Dispose` is called. The `using` statement I used above would guarantee that that will happen.

Comment: Thank you so much,  it worked!  

Now, in Word, when I add an hyperlink to an internal bookmark,  there is no URL, just a "#" in front of the Text ex. "#Bookmark".   Would you happen to know how I could create an URL on self instead of specifying  
"C:\TEMPO\smartbook\test.docx"